# syntax error while working with array

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a function were the first argument would be used as a global variable that holds an array of numbers populated by the rest of the argument but i get a syntax error while assigning the values, but if i just assign a scalar to the variable it works. This is the code below

the value of `new_set_name` which is `a` would hold all the array elements

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

create() {

    local new_set_name=${1}

    shift;

    declare -g ${new_set_name}=( ${@} );    
    echo ${!new_set_name}
}

create a 1 2 3 4

echo ${a[@]}
```

but if i tried it with a scalar it works

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

create() {

    local new_set_name=${1}

    shift;

    declare -g ${new_set_name}=1;

    echo ${!new_set_name}
}

create a 1 2 3 4

echo ${a[@]}
```

am a bit surprised to see it work for scalars and errors are spit out for arrays. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash` 4.3 or later, you can use [`nameref`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

create() {
    local -n name=$1; shift
    name=("$@")
}

create a 1 2 3 4
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
```

```
1
2
3
4
```

---

See [Bash FAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for more information.

Comment: just the answer am looking for thanks, but it seems like there is no documentation for `nameref` , when i do `help -m local` , the `-n` switch was not specified

Comment: @0.sh There is a link in the answer. Click on [*nameref*](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters).

Comment: @0.sh Also, make sure to check out the updated link. And use `help declare` instead of `help local`.

Comment: oh, i thought `local` , `declare`, `typeset` do the same thing ?

Comment: @0.sh The thing is, the `help` for `local` just says `OPTION can
    be any option accepted by 'declare'`. So to see the options, `-n` for example, you need to use `help declare`.